# iOS GPS Sdk timestamp

Tags: ios, gps

I need to get access to the GPS timestamp using iOS location API. I understand that there is a timestamp in the GPS location structure, but I can't seem to confirm whether this is coming from GPS satellites or not.

Comment: There is no guarantee the location value is from GPS or some other form. The `timestamp` property of the `CLLocation` is all you have.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get to the raw GPS data and the `timestamp` property of the `CLLocation` in `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` is set with the system clock. Here's a couple of test runs

System clock correct:

```
16/04/2013 18:53:42
16/04/2013 18:53:42
```

Clock set (in the iPhone settings) 2 hours ahead:

```
16/04/2013 20:55:55
16/04/2013 20:55:56
```